# Função AJAX para atualizar table

Tags: ajax, json

Possuo esta função em AJAX para atualizar os dados de uma tabela, os dados estão vindo correto do controller, porém ele não atualiza com os dados corretos, ele atualiza em branco.

```
function buscaFornecedores(id) {
var url = "/Produto/BuscaFornecedor";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { id: id},
    success: function (data) {
        $("#tabelaf").html(data);
    }
});
```

}

Seria possível fazer algo tipo este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-response-json) ? Utilizo MVC Core Page Razor.

**EDIT**

Eu recebo desta forma os dados, dando um console.log(data.resultado)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT**
Esse é o meu HTML:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tabelaf">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fornecedores</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAdd" title="Adicionar Novo Fornecedor" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
                        {
                            <tr class="tr">
                                <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <a class="link-excluir" href="#" data-id="@item.Id" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Qual o formato da sua resposta ?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: O link que postou exemplifica exatamente o que precisa. Considerou utilizar daquele jeito ? Deu algum erro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
success: function (data) {
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.id+ '</td><td>' + item.fornecedorProduto+ '</td><td>' + item.fornecedorID + '</td><td>' + item.produtoFornecedor+ '</td><td>' + item.produtoID+ '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#tabelaf').append(trHTML);
    }
```

Comment: Eu fiz desta forma, e na tabela apareceu undefined, nos campos, no caso eu utilizo apenas id nesta tabela, e na viewmodel, eu declaro as tabelas para buscar o nome, será que é algo com isso ? Por isso não apareceu o noem correto? Coloquei meu código HTML para que você possa entender. Obrigado.

Comment: Coloquei na função console.log(item.(campo). E todos vem undenifed.